# caret: 'rlang_env_get' not found

Tags: r, tidyselect

I ran `library(caret)` a few days ago, and it worked. Since then I've updated Rtools, and now I'm getting some errors I can't resolve through my usual methods

Information below for error:

```
> library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tidyselect', details:
  call: env_get(base_env(), "unlockBinding")
  error: object 'rlang_env_get' not found
```

similar for `tidyselect`

```
> library(tidyselect)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyselect’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tidyselect', details:
  call: env_get(base_env(), "unlockBinding")
  error: object 'rlang_env_get' not found
```

I've tried `install.packages` with both

```
install.packages("tidyselect", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

When I did that, I could load `tidyselect`, but then not `caret`. I then decided to try the github version of `caret`: `devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')`. This failed with a couple of error messages:

```
Error in is_list(x) : object 'rlang_is_list' not found
Error : unable to load R code in package 'ggplot2'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/.../R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
* restoring previous 'C:/.../R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
```

and

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tidyselect', details:
  call: env_get(base_env(), "unlockBinding")
  error: object 'rlang_env_get' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'caret'
```

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Any ideas on what I should look at would be great. 
Thanks, Jonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://community.rstudio.com/t/difficulty-installing-dev-version-of-ggplot2-due-to-rlang-is-list-not-being-found/8169/8

removing and re-installing `rlang` has done the trick :)